# How to show most common multiple data across values in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet like this.

[image]

Let's call the values in the orange box a recipe
and value selected (太刀・三日月宗近) is the result.

How to find most common recipe for (太刀・三日月宗近) result?

If there is exist any better solutions outside excel, please do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you might do this.

1. Add a new column on the right of your data. Let's title this "Recipe". In row 3 (or wherever your first data row is) concatenate the values in your 4 'recipe' columns, like this:

   `=F3+G3+H3+I3`

   So you'll get a value something like `950950950950なし`. Copy this down the entire length of your "Recipe" column.
2. Insert a Pivot Table. Add the `完成した刀剣名` column to your row labels, then add the 'Recipe' column below that. Finally, add `Recipe` again to your values section of the pivot table.

   You should get something like this:

   [image]